# changing layouts programmatically - android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using sliding tabs and a `navigationdrawer` in my `android` application. In the sliding tabs I have 4 `Fragments` assigned to each tab. And in the `navigationdrawer` also I have the option to choose the mentioned 4 `Fragments` and several other `Fragments`. Now my problem is when I go to a `Fragment` using my sliding tabs, there's no need of a header bar to my layout as user can know which `Fragment` he's in because the tab name is available. But if the user go to a `Fragment` using the `navigationdrawer` a header bar with the name of the `Fragment` is necessary. But as I'm loading the same `Fragment` in tabs and `navigationdrawer`. How can I show a header bar when it's opened from `navigationdrawer` and hide the header bar when opened from tabs.

code for tabs strip:

```
 public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        {
            TopTenFragment tab1 = new TopTenFragment();
            return tab1;
        }
        else if(position == 1)            // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
        {
            SongsFragment tab2 = new SongsFragment();
            return tab2;
        }
        else if(position == 2)
        {

            VideoFragment tab3 = new VideoFragment();
            return tab3;
        }
        else if(position == 3)
        {

            RadioFragment tab4 = new RadioFragment();
            return tab4;
        }


        else{

            return null;
        }
```

Code for navigationdrawer

```
@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {


        if (position == 0) {


            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new Dashboard()).commit();


        }


        if (position == 1) {


            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new ListenLiveFragment()).commit();


        }


        if (position == 2) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new SongsFragment()).commit();


        }


        if (position == 3) {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new VideoFragment()).commit();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments to the fragment through bundle.

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 boolean showTitle = true;
 bundle.putBoolean("showTitle", showTitle);
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

You can then access this bundle in fragments and show/hide the title.

```
boolean showTitle = this.getArguments().getBoolean("showTitle",false);
if(showTitle)
//Show Title
else
//Hide Title
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you :

1. First create a temporary class and declare a integer variable position with deafult as 0
2. next in navigation drawer code for each if condition assign the position variable of temporary class a unique int value
3. now in your fragment onCreateView method put a condition to first check if any position has been set or not if not(it means not called from navigation drawer) if it has been set(the called from navigation drawer)
4. if called from navigation drawer just use this

   ```
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nameoflayout,container, false);
   view.header.setVisibility(Visiblity.VISIBLE);
   ```
5. else

   ```
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nameoflayout,container, false);
   view.header.setVisibility(Visiblity.GONE);
   ```

   Hope it helps!!